# What is the default value of 'Text' parameter in TField.OnGetText

Tags: delphi

I have a procedure attached to `TField.OnGetText` event of field `Score` like this:

```
procedure TMyForm.GetScoreText(Sender: TField; var Text: string; DisplayText: Boolean);
begin
    if StrToInt(Sender.AsString) >= 80 and StrToInt(Sender.AsString) <= 100 then
        Text := 'Great!';
    else if StrToInt(Sender.AsString) >= 60 and StrToInt(Sender.AsString) < 80 then
        Text := 'Good';
end;
```

From [`OnGetText` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/Data.DB.TField.OnGetText), I know that when there is no `OnGetText` handler defined, the `Text` property of the field is the name as `AsString` property. But my question is, what value does the `var` parameter `Text` get there is an `OnGetText` defined but the the `Text` is defined for the current value of the field. That is in my case, what value does the `Text` get when value of the field `Score` is something less than 60? Is it `Null`, or empty string, or something else? I need to know it explicitly because there is some logic that depends on the value being displayed.

I learned from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691415/delphi-setting-ongettext-event-handler-for-fields-of-a-dynamic-query) that there was nothing being displayed for the field when the `OnGetText` handler procedure has no code, that is body of the procedure is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an `OnGetText` assigned and nothing returns in the `Text` argument, then the result is an empty string.

Look at the `Db` source:

```
function TField.GetDisplayText: string;
begin
  Result := '';
  if Assigned(FOnGetText) then
    FOnGetText(Self, Result, True) else
    GetText(Result, True);
end;
```

The `Result` initially is set to an empty string and passes it to the `FOnGetText` if it was assigned.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, where can I see for myself the code you have shown here? That is, I am talking about the source itself ;-)

Comment: Welcome. go to your `uses` section and `CTRL + left-click` on  `Db`.

Comment: BTW, *"Is it Null, or empty string, or something else..."* A `string` cannot be `Null`.

Comment: *A string cannot be Null* - thanks for that. I am not actually coding in delphi, I am converting delphi into C#. Anyway, which IDE provides that `CTRL + left-click`? And any other way without an IDE, because as I already said, I am not developing in delphi, so I shouldn't have an IDE ;-)

Comment: Well, do you have Delphi installed with sources?

Comment: I am not sure, but I have CodeGear RAD Studio installed.

Comment: Look for DB.pas or Data.DB.pas depending on your version in the CodeGear directory.

Comment: The *CodeGear* IDEs predate the introduction of unit scopes in XE2.  The last CodeGear IDE was RAD Studio 2009 (after Embarcadero purchased CodeGear), the first Embarcadero-branded IDE was RADStudio 2010. So the source file name would be `DB.pas` prior to XE2, and `Data.DB.pas` in XE2 onwards.